# Pick up JVM method invocation

Tags: java, android, jvm

How can i log all method calls with it arguments, performed by JVM at runtime, and maybe there is a possiblity to change method arguments, do some stuff before method is called, without changing JVM code itself?

I already had run through

1. Instrumentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html)
2. DTrace with its code (http://github.com/dtrace4linux/linux),

but i am a newbie in how JVM is constructed in it nitty-gritty details, and my main question - is this a right way to start with this code(the code of Dtrace)? Maybe you can give me an article to read?

And also - can i do the same things on ART or dalvik? (not only debuggable applications, with the help of JDWP).

And one more thing - JMVTI is too slow, it takes nearly 300µs on calling handler.

Edited:

links, i got:

https://code.google.com/p/droidbox/

http://mostly-about-java.blogspot.ru/2012/12/methodcallspy-building-own-method_3.html?m=1

https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo

https://www.yourkit.com

Comment: Flagged as unclear because it sounds as though you've asked several different questions that could be related but all would have different answers. If that's actually the case, you need to ask each separately. The wording is also unclear: "...is this a right way to start with this code?" What code? The JVM? The solution to your first question? Your second question?

Comment: Also, I take it this is a desktop JVM question, and you've tagged Android because you're curious whether the solution will also apply to Dalvik/Art?

Comment: Yes, I am curious.  I am an android developer, on my work i used to change aosp code, create our own system apps, but now i want an another, much bigger solution, working with jvm. And, of course, working on android.

Comment: Sorry for not clear question. Let me explain: at the end I want to get a built-in application, which would be able to pick up methods invocation, change their arguments and do custom things with it(for example, on-fly optimization of work for some system applications, maybe via changing the sequence of called methods), which works on all platforms, having java. For me, this project is in researching stage, so i want just get a clear understanding of my course, the right and correct things to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically it is possible on JVM using own [javaagent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html). Alternatively you can use [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) framework and its [Load Time Weaver](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw.html) to simplify this process.

Check [this article](http://mostly-about-java.blogspot.ru/2012/12/methodcallspy-building-own-method_3.html) for sample and repository for some code: https://bitbucket.org/espinosa/methodcallspy0

Unfortunately Dalvik/ART doesn't support javaagent so this will work only on 'real' JVM, but not on android.

Comment: I want an app, working on runtime, in a perfect world - without using hotswap. But - thanks a lot for an information!